# Update Kivy ProgressBar in Real-time from external input

Tags: python, kivy

I have an app which depends on a system app's output as such, to get that output i'm using the `subprocess` module which works great, the problem is that this system app generates outputs as it is running as such I capture the output in realtime(no problem here) and I want to use this same output to update my Kivy `ProgressBar` **in realtime**. So far, i get the output and try to update the progressbar but the application simply hangs and updates the progressbar when the `subprocess` call is finished. here is a simple example.

Assume that the directory structure is like this:

```
project
|----------slow.py
|----------myapp.py
```

Suppose `slow.py` is the file handling the system calls and it gets the outputs and feeds it to a function, here is the minimal code for that

```
from time import sleep

class Slow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def call_me(self, callback):
        for x in range(10):
            sleep(2)
            callback(x)
```

Now for The `myapp.py` code:

```
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App

from slow import Slow

class MyWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.padding = 100
        self.sl = Slow()
        self.pb = ProgressBar()
        self.pb.min=0
        self.pb.max=100

        btn = Button(text='Start Update')
        btn.bind(on_release=self.start_update)

        self.add_widget(self.pb)
        self.add_widget(btn)

    def start_update(self, *args):
        self.sl.call_me(self.update_progress)

    def update_progress(self, progress):
        print(progress)
        self.pb.value = float(progress)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWindow()


MyApp().run()
```

If you run this app, you'll notice it freezes until the counting is done. How can I fix such a scenario?

**NB**: I already tried using `Clock.schedule_once` which, needless to say, gives the same result

Comment: You should run `start_update()` in a separate thread, then run `callback(x)` using `Clock.schedule_once()`.

Comment: @John Anderson, callback is in a separate file that doesnt use kivy at all

Comment: I was looking at your posted code where `self.update_progress` is passed to `call_me()` as the `callback`. Since I can't see your actual code, a general rule is that the code is capturing data from your  `SubProcess` should be run in a separate thread (not the main thread), and each call to `update_progress()` should be called using `Clock.schedule_once()` to get that call back on the main thread (since it updates the GUI).

Comment: Makes sense, I'll try that